# Prove that a matrix is defective or non defective

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\textbf{A}$ be a large ($size>10^6 \times 10^6$) matrix. Other than eigenvectors are independent, what are the conditions on $\textbf{A}$ to prove the matrix is defective or non defective?

A simple way of asking this is, what are the condition on $\textbf A$ so that eigenvectors are linearly independent.

PS: I know that if eigenvalues are known, computing the null space of $\textbf{A}-\lambda \textbf{I}$ for repeated eigenvalues $\lambda$ will give the geometric multiplicity which can be used to confirm the dimension of eigenspace. But I don't want to compute eigenvalues or eigenvectors due the large dimension.

Comment: This answer deals with matlab specifically, but goes over various ways to check if a matrix is singular (same word for what you mean by defective)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145948/how-to-find-out-if-a-matrix-is-singular

Comment: I am disagreeing with your comment. Singular matrix doesn't mean defective matrix. But the link you suggested is helpful for other needs.